# Spivak, Ch. 22, Problem 20: $f$ continuous, sequence $x,f(x),f(f(x)),f(f(f(x))),...$ converges to $l$. Prove that $l$ is a fixed point, ie $f(l)=l$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following problem is from Ch. 22 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 20. Suppose that $f$ is continuous and that the sequence
>
> $$x,f(x),f(f(x)),f(f(f(x))),...\tag{1}$$
>
> converges to $l$. Prove that $l$ is a "fixed point" for $f$, ie
> $f(l)=l$.

I'd like to go through the terse solution manual solution in more intermediate steps to make sure that my understanding of them is correct.

**Here the solution manual solution verbatim**

> Let us denote
>
> $$f(f(f\text{...}f(x)\text{...}))$$
>
> by $f^k(x)$. Then by Theorem 1,
>
> $$f(l)=f(\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f^k(x))=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}
>  f(f^k(x))$$
>
> $$=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f^{k+1}(x)=l$$

**Let me try to go through this with more intermediate steps.**

This solution uses the following theorem

> **Ch. 22, Theorem 1** Let $f$ be a function defined in an open interval containing $c$, except perhaps at $c$ itself, with
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)=l$$
>
> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that
>
> $$(1)\text{ each }a_n\text{ is in the domain of }f,$$
>
> $$(2)\text{ each }a_n\neq c$$
>
> $$(3) \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=c$$
>
> Then the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}$ satisfies
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=l$$
>
> Conversely, if this is true for every sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying
> the above conditions then $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)=l$.

By assumption, $f$ is continuous everywhere. Thus, it is defined everywhere (in particular in an open interval containing $l$), and

$$\lim\limits_{x\to l} f(x)=f(l)$$

This is the antecedent in Theorem 1.

Our sequence is

$$a_n=f^{(n-1)}(x)$$

Does this sequence fulfill the three criteria in Theorem 1?

- By assumption, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^n(x)=l$ (this is criterion $(3)$)
- Each $a_n$ is in the domain of $f$, which is all numbers. (criterion $(1)$)
- As for criterion $(2)$, $a_n$ may be equal to $l$. But since we know that $f$ is defined at $l$, this is okay.

Thus, by Theorem 1, we can infer that the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}$ satisfies

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(f^{(n-1)}(x))=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(x)=l$$

Thus, if we evaluate $f$ at both sides of the equation

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(x)=l$$

we get

$$f(l)=f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(x))\tag{2}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(f^{(n)}(x))\tag{3}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^{(n+1)}(x)=l$$

Thus

$$f(l)=l$$

**Questions**

- Is this understanding of the intermediate steps of the solution manual solution correct?
- What is it that allows us to go from $(2)$ to $(3)$?

Comment: $(2) \implies (3)$ because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: That is what I thought. I had in mind that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(g(x))=f(\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$ if $f$ is continuous at $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$. So in this case, we have $g(n)=f^{(n)}(x)$, and because $f$ is continuous everywhere it is continuous at $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(n)$ and thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(g(n))=f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(n))$

Comment: Let $a_n\to a.$ Then by continuity $f(a_n)\to f(a).$ Define $a_n=f^{(n)}(x).$ Assume $a_n\to a.$ Then $a\leftarrow a_{n+1}=f^{(n+1)}(x)=f(a_n)\to f(a).$Therefore $f(a)=a.$

Comment: "As for criterion (2), $a_n$ may be equal to $l$. But since we know that $f$ is defined at $l$, this is okay." - while this is true, it means you are no longer applying Theorem 1, as that theorem requires $a_n \ne l$. Instead you are applying a distinct, though related, result.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct but I think we just need to take a step back by first extracting ourselves from this problem and convincing ourselves of a simple fact to demonstrate: either $(a_n)_{n\geq0 }$ a sequence of real numbers converging to $l$. Then the sequence $(b_n)_{n\geq0}$ defined by $b_n:=a_{n+1}$
for all $n\geq 0$ is such that $(b_n)_{n\geq0}$ also converges to $l$.
So we come back to our problem:

As you put it, here, $a_n:=f^{(n)}(x)$ for a fixed $x$. $b_n=a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$. By hypothesis, $a_n\to l$ when $n\to +\infty$. And, according to our preliminary remark, the same for $(b_n)_n\color{green}{(1)}$. What allows us to go from (2) to (3) is that $f$ is continuous in $l$: $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(a_n)=f(l)$ , that's to say $\lim_{n \to +\infty} b_n=f(l)\color{green}{(2)}$. From $\color{green}{(1)}$ and $\color{green}{(2)}$, we conclude.